# 555 timer: light LED for 2 seconds

Tags: 555

I turned it on and nothing happens.

Now what?

[image: Circuit]

[image: Breadboard]

Comment: Turn your LED the right way around for a start.

Comment: The long leg is on the + side. Have I drawn the circuit symbol the wrong way round?

Comment: Yes - consider the triangle as if it's an arrow pointing in the direction of conventional current flow.
But now that I look further, your blocky 'symbol' for the 555 has its pins mirrored, and I'm guessing your breadboard circuit is similarly mis-wired. You've probably fried your 555.